# Downgrading Python 2.7.6 to Python 2.6 in Linux

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to uninstall Python 2.7.6 and install 2.6 instead. how can I manage that. which Python command gives (/usr/bin/python). My environment is Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?  I guarantee you it'll break random parts of your system that depend on 2.7.

Comment: Indeed, I am in need to compile a model requires 2.6 (not supported by newer versions).

Comment: I wonder whether I can keep the current version and install the older. then possibilities of switching between them can be investigated

Comment: I don't believe Python 2.7 broke anything notable in 2.6.  Are you sure you can't just use 2.7 for that?

Comment: @jowdder:  yes I am sure

Comment: @jowdder, what if python 2.7 is removed and I want to fix what happened to the system ???

Comment: google for `python virtualenv` it's the standard way of using multiple python builds/releases on one system.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#installation) and install the 2.6 via

```
pyenv install 2.6.9
```

You can create a virtualenv or change the python version [either by var en or file](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#choosing-the-python-version) or call directly via its path `~.pyenv/versions/<version>/bin/python`